# How to display all column in group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have two tables `team` and `bobotteam`, and then I was try this query:

```
SELECT team.id , bobotteam.teamfight/MAX(bobotteam.teamfight)
    FROM team
    INNER JOIN bobotteam on team.id = bobotteam.id
```

Why data only show 1 data even though I have two data in the `bobotteam` table.
IMAGE

[image: Query Table image]
[image: Bobotteam Table image]

Comment: Please provide an example of your tables data and the desired output.

Comment: Because you use inner join and you have only 1 record in team table. Use left join to get both records of bobotteam table.

Comment: if possible give a screenshot of your current tables

Comment: do u use eloquent?

Comment: Wait i will inser img

Comment: @AdamKozlowski : query builder sir .

Comment: @RaonakIslamNiloy, no screenshots please!!! Formatted text is what most people here want.

Comment: @AamirNakhwa : same as that , only one data displaying

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui : done sir

Comment: @RaonakIslamNiloy I've added photos

Comment: Sorry for everything , i'am newbie using this forum -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT team.id , bobotteam.teamfight/(select MAX(bobotteam.teamfight) from bobotteam)
FROM team
INNER JOIN bobotteam on team.id = bobotteam.id
```

Comment: Thanks sir . Problem solved . I dont understand subquery sir . Thank you very much

Comment: `MAX(bobotteam.teamfight)` there is `max()` is group function and need to perform using individual subquery.

Comment: Okeh i understand sir. Thanks you very much